# Change order of two-factor-authentication

Tags: centos-6, pam, google-authenticator

I am testing two-factor-authentication for ssh logins on some CentOS containers in our testing environment.

I compiled my own rpms from github's source, installed and configured everything and have the default setup up and running. I get prompted for the token first and for the user's password afterwards.

What I am trying to do now is changing the order of the two factors. I have a requirement to ask for password first and for the token last, but I haven't been able to configure this.

This is what `/etc/pam.d/sshd` looks like after the installation:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_google_authenticator.so nullokt
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
```

I have tried to move around the parameters of the first section with no luck. For example, if I move the google_authenticator line to the bottom of the firat section, only password authentication is enabled.

Edit:

I have read PAM's documentation, but I cannot achieve this. I have tried to bundle google-authenticator with /etc/pam.d/password-auth, but nothing changed. It is either token first and password second or password only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem on Centos 6.2. It works after I comment out include in pam file as follow. I use [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Google_Authenticator) as a reference.

```
auth       required     pam_unix.so
auth       required     pam_env.so
auth       required     pam_google_authenticator.so
#auth      required     pam_sepermit.so
#auth       include      password-auth
...
```

Comment: The `password-auth` file has more thing about change password, I doesn't have to change the password(or I will change the password by root and use strong password).